# How to compute the formal group law of K-Theory

Tags: reference-request, topological-k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Could anyone point me to a reference where the formal group law of (topological or motivic) K-theory is computed in as much detail as possible?

Comment: There is now discussion of this on the nLab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+K-theory#ComplexOrientationAndFormalGroupLaw

Answer (score 6):

Well, I don't think there can be much detail here: the first Chern class of a line bundle in topological K-theory is defined by $c_1(L)=\pm1\pm[L]$; hence $c_1(L\otimes L')=c_1(L)+c_1(L')\pm c_1(L)c_1(L')$ — so the FGL is just $F(u,v)=u+v\pm uv$ (sign convention varies).

Answer (score 3):

Let $Vect^1(X)$ be isomorphism classes of complex line bundles on $X$. I assume you're familiar with the definition of topological $K^0(X)$.

Let's examine the map $c_1: Vect^1(X) \to K^2(X)$, (recalling that, due to Bott periodicity, $K^0(X) \simeq K^2(X)$).  The group operators are the  tensor product of line bundles (in $Vect^1(X)$) and the tensor product of virtual line bundles (in $K^0(X)$).

Recall that the dimensions multiply when you do the tensor product, so $L_1 \otimes L_2$ is still a line bundle.

Let's say that $c_1(L) = 1-L$ (there are [other choices of Thom class](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200019/why-is-the-first-chern-class-of-a-line-bundle-c-1l-1-l-in-complex-k-theory)), then we'd expect $c_1(L_1 \otimes L_2) = 1 - L_1 \otimes L_2$.

So, how do we express $c_1(L_1 \otimes L_2)$ in terms of a formal group law $F(x,y)$ where $x = c_1(L_1)$, and $y = c_1(L_2))$?

\begin{align*}
 F(x, y) & = x + y - xy \\
 F(c_1(L_1), c_1(L_2)) & = c_1(L_1) + c_1(L_2)  - c_1(L_1)c_1(L_2)  \\
& = (1-L_1) + (1-L_2) - (1-L_1)(1-L_2) \\
& = 2 - L_1 - L_2 - 1 + L_1 + L_2 - L_1 \otimes L_2 \\
& = 1 - L_1 \otimes L_2
\end{align*}